# D3 not always redrawing graph in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a barChart component in my React application. I have a window resize event listener in my code that *SHOULD* redraw the bar chart but it does not always work correctly. What am I missing in my debouncedResize function that is causing it to not always redraw?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import _ from 'lodash';

import './BarChart.css';

const BarChart = ({ dataSet, propertyToDisplay, propertyToAccess, xRangeStart = 0, xRangeEnd = 100, chosenColor }) => {
    const d3Chart = useRef();
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    });

    const update = useRef(false);

    const debouncedResize = useCallback(
        _.debounce(() => {
            d3.selectAll('g').remove();

            setDimensions({
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            });

            // if resize, remove the previous chart
            if (update.current) {
                d3.selectAll('g').remove();
            } else {
                update.current = true;
            }
        }, 100),
        []
    );

    function wrap(text, width) {
        text.each(function () {
            let text = d3.select(this),
                words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                word,
                line = [],
                lineNumber = 0,
                lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
                y = text.attr('y'),
                dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
                tspan = text
                    .text(null)
                    .append('tspan')
                    .attr('x', 0)
                    .attr('y', y)
                    .attr('dy', dy + 'em');
            while ((word = words.pop())) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text
                        .append('tspan')
                        .attr('x', 0)
                        .attr('y', y)
                        .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
                        .text(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    const margin = { top: 50, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 };

    const DrawChart = (data) => {
        // const maxValue = data.reduce((accum, curr) => {
        //  return accum[propertyToAccess] > curr[propertyToAccess] ? accum : curr;
        // })[propertyToAccess];
        // document.getElementById(`d3KCDashboardChart-${title}`).remove();
        // const createSvg = document.createElement('svg');
        // createSvg.setAttribute('id', `d3KCDashboardChart-${title}`);
        // const chartElement =
        // console.log(d3.select(d3Chart.current), 'first');
        // console.log(d3.select(d3Chart.current).select('svg'), 'second');
        // d3.select(`d3KCDashboardChart-${title}`).remove();
        let chartWidth = d3.select(`.d3KCDashboardChart`).node();
        chartWidth = chartWidth.getBoundingClientRect().width;

        const chartHeight = 200;
        let colors;

        if (!chosenColor) {
            colors = ['#4e5f78'];
        } else {
            colors = chosenColor;
        }

        const svg = d3
            .select(d3Chart.current)
            .attr('width', chartWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', chartHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        const x = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(d3.range(data.length))
            .range([margin.left, chartWidth + margin.right])
            .padding(0.1);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${chartHeight})`)
            .call(
                d3
                    .axisBottom(x)
                    .tickFormat((i) => data[i][propertyToDisplay])
                    .tickSizeOuter(0)
                    .tickPadding(10)
            )
            .selectAll('text')
            // .attr("transform", "rotate(-15)")
            .style('font-size', '11px')
            .call(wrap, x.bandwidth());

        const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([xRangeStart, xRangeEnd]).range([chartHeight, margin.top]);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('fill', (d, i) => {
                return colors[i];
            })
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
            .join('rect')
            // How we can make bars clickable for future use
            // .on('click', () => {
            //  window.location.replace('https://www.google.com');
            // })
            .attr('x', (d, i) => x(i))
            .attr('y', (d) => y(d[propertyToAccess]))
            .attr('height', (d) => y(0) - y(d[propertyToAccess]))
            .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
            .attr('fill', (d, i) => {
                return colors[i];
            })
            .append('text')
            .text((d) => {
                return d[propertyToAccess];
            });

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left} ,0)`)
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .call(
                d3
                    .axisLeft(y)
                    .tickFormat((d) => `${d}`)
                    .tickSizeInner(-chartWidth)
                    .tickSizeOuter(0)
            );

        // create labels
        svg.append('g')
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
            .style('font', '24px sans-serif')
            .selectAll('text')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('class', 'label');

        // position labels
        svg.selectAll('.label')
            .data(data)
            .attr('x', (d, index) => x(index) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + 20)
            .text((d) => `${d[propertyToAccess]}`)
            // to exclude the animation, remove these two lines
            .transition()
            .delay((d, i) => i * 20)
            //
            .attr('y', (d) => {
                return y(d[propertyToAccess]) - 5;
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Listen for any resize event update
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            debouncedResize();
        });
        if (dataSet && dataSet.length > 0) {
            DrawChart(dataSet, dimensions);
        }
    }, [dataSet, dimensions]);

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '85%' }} className="d3KCDashboardChart">
            <svg ref={d3Chart} />
            {!dataSet || (dataSet.length === 0 && <p>Currently no data to display</p>)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default BarChart;
```

Here is a gif of the issue in action:

[image: Issue Gif]